# Anyone know of a good OCR / Tesseract for Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In need of an OCR module that I can use with my app, but having trouble running the only one I could fine (from 3 years ago :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This Appcelerator marketplace module might help you: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/18033#!overview

Answer (score 0):

Here are two modules based on Tesseract:

- [ocrdroid](https://github.com/juancgarcia/ocrdroid) (android)
- [TiTesseract](https://github.com/stumsky/TiTesseract-for-iOS) (ios)

My experience with Tesseract is that it should be extensively trained (and possibly modified) to achieve reasonable precision.  Image processing will likely be a key part of the workflow.

Instead of Tesseract, [MyScript's SDK](http://myscript.com/technology/#developer-kits) may be a possible OCR solution that's also optimized for handwriting, etc.  I'm not sure if they have a Ti module pre-built.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I run this service.

Consider http://ocrestful.com if your use-case doesn't demand you be able to do it offline.